# Can edit form be inserted between two rows in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, edit

I'm sure can be done with some customization, but maybe a better way than what I would do:

- I need to insert an edit form between two rows in the jqgrid.  (The modal dialog or inline editing will not meet requirements, must be between two rows.  An example, click on 2nd row of 10, and 2nd & 3rd rows separate, pushing 3rd thru 10th rows down, then an editor showing between 2nd & 3rd row appears, 2nd row (whatever row clicked on) populates that edit form for editing).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently, I would simply insert a <div> between two <tr> in the grid to do this.  Maybe someone has better way?